# SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE and @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')") return 403 error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a SPring entry point that needs a JWT Token.
I decoded the token and obtain an object :

```
{
  "aud": "mySite",
  "sub": "admin@mysite.fr",
  "iss": "My Company",
  "Authorities": [
    "WRITE_AUTHORITY",
    "READ_AUTHORITY",
    "DELETE_AUTHORITY",
    "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
  ],
  "exp": 1610910605,
  "iat": 1610046605
}
```

We can note that I have an array of authorities.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping(
        path = "/langs",
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
)
public LangResponseModel addSiteLang(@RequestBody LangRequestModel langRequestModel) {
    log.info("addLang() called");
    LangResponseModel returnValue;

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new CustomMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    LangDto lang = modelMapper.map(langRequestModel, LangDto.class);
    LangDto createdLang = siteService.addGlobalLang(lang);

    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdLang, LangResponseModel.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

My WebSecurity class seems correctly implemented with my public URLs and the ones which require authentication.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // define public & private entry points
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                   // my public entry points here
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    // .addFilter(getUserAuthenticationFilter())
                    // .addFilter(getAdminAuthenticationFilter())
                        .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider))
                        .addFilter(new AdminAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider))
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

I do have the right authorities...

But I obtain 403 error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-07T19:33:23.963+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/app-ws/sites/langs"
}
```

Comment: I use different casing from you, like `Role_USER`

Comment: if you check your debug logs it will tell you exactly why you are getting a 403

Comment: I have this error : An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext. Weird. It just displayed after a mvn clean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what went wrong. I want to implement 2 distintive AuthorizationFilter, because I handle Users and Admins separatelly.

```
.addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider))
.addFilter(new AdminAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider))
```

I just add to remove one authorizationFilter... good